From app insights i get the following Exception Message: A partner claim with id 'identifier' is not found however is required in technical profile
I keep getting this error message in my app insights when i try to authenticate:

Exception Message:A partner claim with id 'identifier' is not found however is required in technical profile 'GenerateOtp' in policy 'B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Signin' of tenant 'omitted.onmicrosoft.com'., Exception Type:InvalidReferenceException, CorrelationID:abcc289d-4e1f-449f-a23f-0627b8d6fef7

But the identifier is already in the GenerateOtp tech profile. What am I missing here?
This is the xml file:
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="omitted.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://omitted.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>omitted.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="otp">
        <DisplayName>Secondary One-time password</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="emailRequestBody">
        <DisplayName>SendGrid request body</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="VerificationCode">
        <DisplayName>Secondary Verification Code</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Enter your email verification code</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="subject">
        <DisplayName>Email subject</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="message">
        <DisplayName>Email message</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="codeIntro">
        <DisplayName>Email code introduction</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="signature">
        <DisplayName>Email signature</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>

    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" TransformationMethod="GetLocalizedStringsTransformation">
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="email_subject" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="message" TransformationClaimType="email_message" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="codeIntro" TransformationClaimType="email_code" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signature" TransformationClaimType="email_signature" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
          <!-- <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.subject" /> -->
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.email" />
          <!-- <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="message" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.message" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="codeIntro" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.codeIntro" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signature" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.signature" /> -->
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <!-- TBD <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="yoursendgridtemplateid"/> -->
          <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="d-omitted" />
          <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="servicedesk@omitted.com" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.2</DataUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.es" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.2</DataUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.es" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.custom-email.en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <!--Email template parameters-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_subject">Contoso account email verification code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_message">Thanks for validating the account</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_code">Your code is</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_signature">Sincerely</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Display control sign-up UI elements-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="intro_msg">Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="success_send_code_msg">Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="failure_send_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please enter a valid email address and try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="success_verify_code_msg">E-mail address verified. You can now continue.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="failure_verify_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_send_code">Send verification code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_verify_code">Verify code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_send_new_code">Send new code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationControl" StringId="but_change_claims">Change e-mail</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Display control password reset UI elements-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="intro_msg">Verification is necessary. Please click Send button.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="success_send_code_msg">Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="failure_send_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please enter a valid email address and try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="success_verify_code_msg">E-mail address verified. You can now continue.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="failure_verify_code_msg">We are having trouble verifying your email address. Please try again.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_send_code">Send verification code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_verify_code">Verify code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_send_new_code">Send new code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="emailVerificationSSPRControl" StringId="but_change_claims">Change e-mail</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Claims-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="emailVerificationCode" StringId="DisplayName">Verification Code</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="emailVerificationCode" StringId="UserHelpText">Verification code received in the email.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="emailVerificationCode" StringId="AdminHelpText">Verification code received in the email.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="email" StringId="DisplayName">Email</LocalizedString>
          <!-- Email validation error messages-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfSessionDoesNotExist">You have exceeded the maximum time allowed.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfMaxRetryAttempted">You have exceeded the number of retries allowed.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfInvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfSessionConflict">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfVerificationFailedRetryAllowed">The verification has failed, please try again.</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.custom-email.es">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <!-- Email validation error messages-->
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_subject">Código de verificación del correo electrónico de la cuenta de Contoso</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_message">Gracias por comprobar la cuenta de </LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_code">Su código es</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_signature">Sinceramente</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
    </Localization>
    <DisplayControls>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationSSPRControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims></OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-CheckEmailAddressExists" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp">
                <Preconditions>
                  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                    <Value>objectId</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                  </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
              </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>One time password technical profiles</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
          <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">60</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
            <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
            <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
            <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">2</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="VerifyOtp">
          <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>RestfulProvider</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SendOtp">
          <DisplayName>Use SendGrid's email API to send the code the the user</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">emailRequestBody</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SendGridSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateEmailRequestBody" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </DisplayClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-CheckEmailAddressExists">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Reset Password</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationSSPRControl"/>
          </DisplayClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInV2">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
            <!-- Existing CombinedSignInAndSignUp Step -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 2: Registration Step if user is not registered -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <Preconditions>
                    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                        <Value>objectId</Value>
                        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                    </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 3: Generate OTP -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="GenerateOtpExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 4: Send OTP -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="SendOtpExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 5: Prompt User to Enter OTP and Verify -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyOtp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 6: Fetch User Attributes if not already done -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 7: Issue Token -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
        </OrchestrationSteps>
        <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>

    <!-- SignIn Journey with OTP Verification -->
    <UserJourney Id="SignInJourney">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
            <!-- Step 1: Prompt for Sign-In -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 2: Generate OTP for Sign-In -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="GenerateOtpExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 3: Send OTP for Sign-In -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="SendOtpExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 4: Prompt User to Enter OTP for Verification -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyOtp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 5: Fetch User Attributes after Verification -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

            <!-- Step 6: Issue Token after Successful Sign-In -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
        </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>

  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>


Are you still facing the issue? @Quoter

"email" is not defined on your ClaimsSchema, can you add that?

@Jahnavi yes unfortunately.

@Lennart-, its defined in the base xml file.

if you guys are still intrested in helping, i hosted the 4 xml files on this website: https://pastebin.com/2V3aYite Im already stuck with this for 4 months. Thanks in advance.
